# Put children around the parent in the forest

Tags: forest, alignment

How can I put `Dan`, `Eve`, and `Frank` under the mother node?
I tried changing anchor points and level distances but I couldn't put these children on the same horizontal level as the parent.

I prefer a solution that locally solves this problem, i.e., adding parameters to the nodes rather than changing the global settings of the forest, as I have a predefined macro based on this forest settings.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={  calign = first,
            grow=west,
            inner sep=0,
            outer sep=0,
            child anchor=east,
            l sep=5mm,
            s sep=8mm,
            anchor=north east
         }
[\begin{tabular}{l}A very wide and\\
tall parent node that\\ 
needs to have\\ 
its choldren surrounded\\
from left and bottom
\end{tabular}
 [Ann]
 [Bill]
 [Carl]
 [Dan]
 [Eve]
 [Frank]
]         
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if you want to use the forest package for this?

Answer (score 6):

If this is part of a larger tree, doing this with Forest is not unreasonable. If, however, your tree is limited to this structure, Ti*k*Z is a better option as you basically have to manually position the nodes anyway.

Note that `tabular` is never required in a Forest tree. Just use `align=<tabular specification>`. You get a tabular with `align` anyway.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    calign child = 2,
    s sep'=8mm,
  },
  grow=-125,
  before drawing tree={
    for children={
      if={ > O_< {n}{4} }{x/.option=!u3.x}{y/.option=!u4.y}
    },
  },
  [A very wide and\\tallparent node that\\needs to be\\surrounded by its children\\from left and bottom, align=left
    [Ann]
    [Bill]
    [Carl]
    [Dan]
    [Eve]
    [Frank]
 ]         
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes positioned around root]

You can adjust the angle of growth, `calign child` and/or `s sep'` as desired. If you don't want the order of the children reversed, use `grow'` rather than `grow`.

Personally, if this was the structure I needed, I'd be tempted to do something more like this:

[image: nodes positioned around root alternatively designed]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [align=center] (r) {A very wide and\\tall parent node that\\needs to be surrounded\\by its children from\\left and bottom};
  \foreach \i  [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {180+(18*\j)}] in {Ann,Bill,Carl,Dan,Eve,Frank} \draw (r) -- +(\k:30mm) node [anchor={180+\k}] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```